# How to setup relative import in python?

Tags: python, import

My project tree is as simple as:

```
test
  ├── __init__.py (has line: "foo = True")
  ├── bar.py (has line: "bar = False")
  └── test.py (has line: "from . import foo; from .bar import bar")
```

But none of the imports in `test.py` work. When I run `python test.py`, it returns: `attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Did I miss anything here? I am using python 3.7.6

Comment: from what path are you running `python test.py` ? is it from the test folder itself?

Comment: @MahendraSinghMeena i runned in test folder, and one level above test folder, none worked. basically `python test.py`, and `python test/test.py`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28154841/13782669

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, but the test file needs to be imported **as part of a package**. So I created the following files and directories, exactly how you explained:

```
.
└── test
    ├── bar.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    └── test.py
```

From the parent of `test`, I ran this:

```py
>>> import test
>>> import test.test
>>> import test.bar
>>>
```

It worked fine. But if you're doing relative imports, the code you're importing needs to be imported as part of a package, not executed as a standalone script.

Comment: could you explain "needs to be imported as part of a package"? I am not clear on this

Comment: The original code/script you run needs to be something that imports the package `test.py` is part of. In other words, the package must already be imported *outside of the test package* by the time `test.py` runs.

Answer (score 1):

the issue is arising because you are trying to import `foo` from `__init__.py` file as  `from . import foo` , but to import from `__init__.py` file you need to use a parent folder module, ie `from test import foo` as how it is structured to import from `__init__.py`.

Comment: so how can i use something like `from . import something`? according to this article https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/, `from . import something` should work if something is defined in __init__.py

Comment: you can import it as `from __init__ import foo`, why it is failing, maybe related to python version or article being out of date, this may [help](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to import files from the same folder you are, just use their file names:

bar.py

```
bar = False
```

foo.py

```
foo = True
```

test.py

```
from foo import foo
from bar import bar

print(foo, bar)
```

Running `python test.py` returns:

```
True False
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the same/similar file structure, I can think of 2 ways to do imports:

1. Use absolute import if all three files are in the same directory level, so
   `test.py` should look like:

   ```
   import foo
   import bar
   ```

   and `python test.py` should run fine from the `test` directory.
2. Move `foo.py` and `bar.py` into a new directory, let's call it `package`, so the structure will be changed now to:

   ```
   test/
   ├── package
   │   ├── bar.py
   │   └── foo.py
   └── test.py
   ```

   And test.py will be:

   ```
   from package import bar
   from package import foo
   ```

   `python test.py` from the `test` directory will work.